# todonotes: Insertion of chapters headers in the list of to-dos

Tags: todonotes

For `todonotes` package, I would like to know how to insert chapters headers inside the list of to-dos to group them under their respective chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes,lipsum}


\begin{document}

    \listoftodos

    \chapter{1st Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    \todo[inline]{1st todo}

    \chapter{2nd Chapter}
    \lipsum[2]
    \todo[inline]{2nd todo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in the preamble of the document (i.e., before `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\let\ori@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ori@chapter[#1]{#2}%
  \if@mainmatter\addcontentsline{tdo}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}{#1}}%
  \else\addcontentsline{tdo}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after compiling, I found that the chapter header in the main text was changed to numeric (e.g. 1) instead of my original title (e.g. 1st chapter)

Comment: @Diaa Abidou: Corrected.